# Struggling with intro to JSoup

Tags: java, maven, url, jsoup, pom.xml

Hello there StackOverflow. I've never actually posted on here but have used it as a reference and to learn various topics regarding programming countless times so I thank you all for that :)

I'd like to be upfront with this that this is a project that is part of an ongoing interview for an internship position. The company was very kind and offered to help should I get stuck at all on multiple occasions, but I would like to try and get this done on my own if possible as to show that I can resolve my issues through my own findings.

That being said, I've been given a pom.xml file, a skeleton main (in which inserted a very basic attempt to grab a title from a URL).

I'm never used (or even heard of) pom file's until this project so they're still very, *very* new to me.

I'm currently trying to follow [this reference](http://www.javatpoint.com/jsoup-example-print-title-of-an-url) but when I try to run that program I'm getting hit with this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup
    at com.appdetex.sampleparserjavaproject.Main.main(Main.java:26) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.Jsoup
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

Here is the given pom.xml file, to which I haven't changed at all to this point:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.appdetex</groupId>  
    <artifactId>sampleparserjavaproject</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>sampleparserjavaproject</name>
    <url>**Not actually *'s, just wish to hide the github URL**</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ http://jsoup.org/ -->
          <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
          <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and here is my current source code. [NOTE: The Java:26 from my error is the line that contains Document doc = .....]

```
package com.appdetex.sampleparserjavaproject;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
/**
 * Main Java Class
 */
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.javatpoint.com").get();
       String title = doc.title();
       System.out.println("URL title = " + title);     
    } // End of main method
} // End of class Main
```

I'm running the project via the below command:

```
$ java -cp target/sampleparserjavaproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.appdetex.sampleparserjavaproject.Main
```

If I comment out the 3 lines in my main() and just print a "Hello World" for example it works properly, but the JSoup doesn't seem to want to cooperate.

Having essentially no experience with both JSoup and pom files, I'm not too sure what to do next, but from what I've seen it looks like I have to change/edit my pom file somehow.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
- Jack

Comment: I tested your code with jsoup-1.7.2.jar, its working.Check your classpath once wether jsoup jar file there or not. If not add jar file to classpath(lib folder).

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Do you mean the classpath for java?

Comment: check your lib folder.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not understanding what you're saying. Isn't the first part of my compilation command suppose to take care of that?

Comment: do you have any folder structure or simple Java class?

Comment: From where I'm running the program I have 2 folders with the following systems.


1: src -> main -> java -> com -> appdetex -> sampleparserjavaproject -> Main.java


and
2: target -> my .jar file


To clarify, I'm running the program, and in the folder that I'm running it, I also have 2 folders named target and src

Comment: i cant get you. Anyway your problem is your Jsoup jar file is not in classpath.

Comment: Hey there, try inserting `<scope>compile</scope>` below `<version></version` under `<dependencies></dependencies>`

Comment: @JoelMin Awesome! Thanks for the tip! But where exactly do you think it should go? Directly Under <version> would put it on top of <dependencies>, unless you think that's where should go under both. The working kind of confused me on that one. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Oh, sorry for the confusion. Just put it under the `version` tag which is under the `dependencies` tag. See you have two `version` tag? I mean the one inside `dependencies`

Comment: Something like this:

`<version>1.8.3</version>
 <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>`

Comment: @JoelMin Okay, I added it in where you said, at it compiled ok, but when I try to run it, it still is erroring out with the same errors. Thanks again

Comment: What kind of ide are you using?

Comment: @joelMin I'm using xCode to write the .java file, then compiling via the noted command in the original post. I'm still very new to this type of programming and haven't figured out how to program using a pom.xml in Eclipse (which is where I normally program in)

Comment: Please, take a look to [this manual](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/public-book.html) to know what is maven and how to use it in your Java projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be struggling with basic project setup for a Maven project. Maven uses pom files to define how the project parts work together. Mostly, they contain information about compile time and run time dependencies.

To use this properly in Eclipse you should use the m2eclipse plugin, which is probably already part of your installation.

There are many tutorials about Maven and how it works. I found this one very good: http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-java-project-with-maven/

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!! For whatever reason when I run from command line it doesn't work, but when I run from within Eclipse it works as it should. Thank you again and have a wonderful weekend!

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to want to launch on the command line, you could issue:

```
mvn -DmainClass=com.appdetex.sampleparserjavaproject.Main compile exec:java
```

For more details, check the Exec Maven Plugin at http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html